# What is AWS Aurora Serverless scale up time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to build a python app and plan to use AWS Aurora Serverless. I looked into the docs and while they have mentioned scale downtime, I couldn't find the scale uptime. any pointers?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html

Comment: Are you interested in the cooldown times? If so, "There is no cooldown period for scaling up. Aurora Serverless can scale up whenever necessary, including immediately after scaling up or scaling down."

Answer (score 0):

AWS Aurora Serverless v1 scales up time is usually a few seconds. But now v2 scales up in just milliseconds.

Comment: In practice I found the scale up time for v1 to be close to 30-45s